# How to type safe a method param?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to build a method called `updater` which will accept a method parameter that will return the generic type of `updater` (`State`).
It works well, however it doesn't seem type safe as I can add a property which doesn't exist on my interface. And I don't want to be able to do that, I want tslint to catch that as an error. How can I do so?

On the other hand, when I simply type the return type a new method (`test2`), it correctly display the error as `other` doesn't exist.

[Here is a reproduction](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpjpZBvAsAKGSOQQHsBbABzhAE8AuZAZzClAHMDjlgATRkAFdyAI2gBuAgF8CZECx4hgYYHAA26TBEaasAXhxdiZKjQbIA5DFKkLAGiNE%20jAKzSCBGIJAIVpEMiClLxaUAA8ACoAfAAU1FBw5IwxLFqMEQCUyHpRyJmGhMb%20TKRqEAB0aqTscXAJ5Bnu%20AQA9C3IAJLIvP4WYMgA7jT9YKTIYshwImXIo5O8vJakYAAW0Bae3r7A-rMQLACMMVl4hciOgcGhYboQsSkYkFk552fcyDGn79-I5X%20pkAcbx%20PH4yAAbECQdxlmsoIwLBtgcQpI03miZM18G1ZitgEweASyFAoBBfGpaLNaJQUEw4DAIJsfH4ApAWAAmY46R4oL7EUlgQRQAJ875-cqgZSqDQ8qE-EzUOgI9g2dhlewXGGraAIpHcTFSIA)

```
interface State {
    company: string
    id: number;
}
const initialState: State = {
    company: 'foo',
    id: 5
}

function updater<T>(param: (state: T) => T) {
    console.log(param)
}

// I don't want to be able to add 'other'
function test1() {
   
    updater<State>((state) => 
        ({
            ...state,
            id: 6,
            other: ''
        })
    )
}

// this is correctly type safe
function test2(): State {
    return {
        ...initialState,
        company: 'google',
        other: ''
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding a constraint to the generic param `T`. For example `function updater<T extends State>(....)`

Comment: I've tried to add this and it didn't change anything :/

Comment: This is known issue (excess property checking doesn't work in callbacks) https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7547. PR aiming to fix this https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40311

Comment: Oh boy! Thanks Aleksey